# Bringing in a function from javascript into html

Tags: javascript, html, function, import

New to web programming but need to make a web app for some existing c++ code. I have already gotten the existing c++ code to compile in javascript. I can output the values in a js file with a function called sample(), but I cannot figure out how to bring this function into the html front end that I have so that I can use these generated values.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: HTML is front end for the client-side. What do you mean by bring the function to html front end?

Comment: Please show us that generated `sample` function, and tell us *how* you want them to have displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your code inside *script* tag:

```
<script>

var func = function() {
   // ...
}

</script>
```

To show something inside a html element:

```
<div id="my-element"></div>

<script>
var func = function() {
   return 'result';
}
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("my-element").innerHTML = func();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I already have the the script tags in but how do I get the html to display the return value of this function?

Comment: Just edited my answer. Is that what you are searching for.

Comment: Creating an anonymous function, assigning it to a variable, then creating a further anonymous function seems somewhat Byzantine to me. And overwriting the onload handler rather than using attachEvent/addEventListener is a bit messy. But at least you didn't suggest  using document.write()

Comment: My function represents the function mentioned by the OP. I agree about window.onload. However, if you use attachEvent/addEventListener you will still have a closure.

Answer (score 0):

You can you jQuery as you are a begginer. For example you could do this:

```
<script>
var myName = "Martin";

$("#personName").html(myName);

</script>
```

See example here.
http://jsbin.com/oQEVEji/1/edit

You could also use the native code [document.getElementById('personName')](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)[.innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) =  myName